# Filter 2 models with ContentType in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 profile Models. And I am creating an "Attendee" object. How do I filter just between the 2 profiles?

```
class Profile1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)

class Profile2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    # This filters through everything... How do I filter down just to the 2 profile objects?
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profile = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you want to filter `attendees` by `profile1` or `profile2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [ContentType model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) has three fields `app_label`, `model` and `name`. So you can easily filter through these fields.

```
attendees = Attendee.objects.filter(content_type__model = 'Profile1')
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Another question. How do I get those filter options in the admin?... Ie: When selecting `content_type` and just having to choose from profile1 and profile2?

Comment: @Modelesq Post this as a new question with some more info.

Comment: With recent django, it seems that the model name is lowercase (profile1). The @Boern solution seems to be more secure

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
...

Attendee.objects.filter(
   content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Profile1))
```

to avoid comparing strings and bugs after refactoring classnames.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer