# How to filter multiple fields with list of objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to build an webapp like [Quora](http://www.quora.com/) or [Medium](https://medium.com), where a user can follow users or some topics.

eg: userA is following (userB, userC, tag-Health, tag-Finance).

These are the models:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField('auth.user')
    follows_user = models.ManyToManyField('Relationship', related_name='followed_by')
    follows_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Activity(models.Model):
    actor_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='actor_type_activities')
    actor_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    actor = GenericForeignKey('actor_type', 'actor_id')
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    target_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='target_type_activities')
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_type', 'target_id')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Now, this would give the following list:

```
following_user = userA.relationship.follows_user.all()
following_user
[<Relationship: userB>, <Relationship: userC>]
following_tag = userA.relationship.follows_tag.all()
following_tag
[<Tag: tag-job>, <Tag: tag-finance>]
```

To filter I tried this way:

```
Activity.objects.filter(Q(actor__in=following_user) | Q(tags__in=following_tag))
```

But since actor is a GenericForeignKey I am getting an error:

> FieldError: Field 'actor' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

How can I filter the activities that will be unique, with the list of users and list of tags that the user is following? To be specific, how will I filter GenericForeignKey with the list of the objects to get the activities of the following users.

Comment: OT: I successfully used this package (in production on a non trivial webapp) for the use case you describe : https://github.com/bitmazk/django-object-events.

Comment: hi @Aamu, Could you plz let me know, if just doing this gets you results without problems.. `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=following_user) ` works.?

Comment: @simonecittadini Thank you. I will surely check this out.

Comment: @Trying2Learn No, `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=following_user)` is what's throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the `docs` are suggesting is not a bad thing.

The problem is that when you are creating `Activities` you are using `auth.User` as an `actor`, therefore you can't add `GenericRelation` to `auth.User` *(well maybe you can by monkey-patching it, but that's not a good idea)*.

#### So what you can do?

**@Sardorbek Imomaliev** solution is very good, and you can make it even better if you put all this logic into a custom `QuerySet` class. *(the idea is to achieve DRY-ness and reausability)*

```
class ActivityQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(
            models.Q(
                actor_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user),
                actor_id__in=user.relationship.follows_user.values_list('id', flat=True)
            )|models.Q(
                tags__in=user.relationship.follows_tag.all()
            )
        )

class Activity(models.Model):
    #..
    objects = ActivityQuerySet.as_manager()

#usage
user_feed = Activity.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

#### but is there anything else?

**1.** Do you really need `GenericForeignKey` for `actor`? I don't know your business logic, so probably you do, but using just a regular `FK` for actor (just like for the `tags`) will make it possible to do staff like `actor__in=users_following`.

**2.** Did you check if there isn't an app for that? One example for a package already solving your problem is [django-activity-steam](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) check on it.

**3.** IF you don't use `auth.User` as an `actor` you can do exactly what the `docs` suggest -> adding a `GenericRelation` field. In fact, your `Relationship` class is suitable for this purpose, but I would really rename it to something like `UserProfile` or at least `UserRelation`. Consider we have renamed `Relation` to `UserProfile` and we create new `Activities` using `userprofile` instead. The idea is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField('auth.user')
    follows_user = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile', related_name='followed_by')
    follows_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    activies_as_actor = GenericRelation('Activity',
        content_type_field='actor_type',
        object_id_field='actor_id',
        related_query_name='userprofile'
    )


class ActivityQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def for_userprofile(self, userprofile):
        return self.filter(
            models.Q(
                userprofile__in=userprofile.follows_user.all()
            )|models.Q(
                tags__in=userprofile.relationship.follows_tag.all()
            )
        )


class Activity(models.Model):
    #..
    objects = ActivityQuerySet.as_manager()

#usage

#1st when you create activity use UserProfile
Activity.objects.create(actor=request.user.userprofile, ...)

#2nd when you fetch. 
#Check how `for_userprofile` is implemented this time
Activity.objects.for_userprofile(request.user.userprofile)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should just filter by ids.

First get ids of objects you want to filter on

```
following_user = userA.relationship.follows_user.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
following_tag = userA.relationship.follows_tag.all()
```

Also you will need to filter on actor_type. It can be done like this [for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753580/filter-models-based-on-content-type-django-1-7)

```
actor_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(userA.__class__)
```

Or as @Todor suggested in comments. Because [`get_for_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model) accepts both model class and model instance

```
actor_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(userA)
```

And than you can just filter like this.

```
Activity.objects.filter(Q(actor_id__in=following_user, actor_type=actor_type) | Q(tags__in=following_tag))
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go as well, as far as I understand a GenericForeignKey will not give you access to the QuerySet, so you have to filter yourself on the Model and object id's, a bit like a composite key.

Comment: I just want to mention that `ContentType.objects.get_for_model` works with a model class or an instance of a model. So its perfectly fine to: `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(userA)`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey):

> Due to the way GenericForeignKey is implemented, you cannot use such fields directly with filters (filter() and exclude(), for example) via the database API. Because a GenericForeignKey isn’t a normal field object, these examples will not work:

You could follow what the error message is telling you, I think you'll have to add a GenericRelation relation to do that. I do not have experience doing that, and I'd have to study it but...

Personally I think this solution is too complex to what you're trying to achieve. If only the `user` model can follow a tag or authors, why not include a ManyToManyField on it. It would be something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    follow_tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    follow_author = models.ManyToManyField('Author')
```

You could query all followed tag activities per Person like this:

```
Activity.objects.filter(tags__in=person.follow_tag.all())
```

And you could search 'persons' following a tag like this:

```
Person.objects.filter(follow_tag__in=[<tag_ids>])
```

The same would apply to authors and you could use querysets to do OR, AND, etc.. on your queries.

If you want more models to be able to follow a tag or author, say a `System`, maybe you could create a `Following` model that does the same thing `Person` is doing and then you could add a `ForeignKey` to `Follow` both in `Person` and `System`

Note that I'm using this `Person` to meet this [recomendation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Sorry, I had the model like yours, I forgot to update it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the GenericRelation?

Answer (score 1):

You can query seperately for both usrs and tags and then combine them both to get what you are looking for. Please do something like below and let me know if this works..

```
usrs = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=following_user)    
tags = Activity.objects.filter(tags__in=following_tag)

result = usrs | tags
```

Comment: `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=following_user)` this is throwing the above error. `Activity.objects.filter(tags__in=following_tag)` is working fine.

Comment: Does this work `user_ids = following_user.values_list('id', flat=True)`  ... `usrs = Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=user_ids)`?

Comment: `Activity.objects.filter(actor__in=user_ids)` giving me the same error (`FieldError: Field 'actor' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.
`).

Comment: Did you try creating a GenericRelation for the same? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotate to join the two primary keys as a single string then use that to filter your queryset.

```
from django.db.models import Value, TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

following_actor = [
    # actor_type, actor
    (1, 100),
    (2, 102),
]
searchable_keys = [str(at) + "__" + str(actor) for at, actor in following_actor]

result = MultiKey.objects.annotate(key=Concat('actor_type', Value('__'), 'actor_id', 
                                              output_field=TextField()))\
    .filter(Q(key__in=searchable_keys) | Q(tags__in=following_tag))
```